# Where did the sin(kx)/(kx) term in the two-point correlation function $\xi(x)$ come from?

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, correlation

In my cosmology textbook, there is a derivation of the two-point correlation function (assuming statistically homogeneous and isotropic fluctuations). I follow the derivation up to equation (7.8a). However, between (7.8a) and (7.8b), there is a sin(kx)/(kx) function which has been inserted, and I don't understand why it's been added. I think it might have something to do with the fourier transform of a rectangular function being the sinc(x) function, but I'm not sure how rectangular functions are applicable to the context of the correlation function.

[image]
[image]

Textbook: The Physics of Cosmology, George Efstathiou.

Comment: Hint: evaluate $\int_0^\pi e^{-ikx\cos\theta}\sin\theta\mathrm{d}\theta$.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks, I think I've worked it out now.